# add a no image placeholder on elementor pro post element if there is no featured image

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

is there filter of some sort that can add a image if there is no featured image present when using the **Elementor pro** "post" element.

Because the title goes up if there is no image placed and it breaks the sites display

[image]

want to add a placeholder image like below when no featured image is available

[image]

Comment: Is Elementor using different field for featured image than the default that wp is using?

Comment: @kaize, its just using the default wp function, I did not edit anything

Comment: Dont delete this image, Im using it in production. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can add this filter to you theme `functions.php` :

```
function mlnc_filter_post_thumbnail_html( $image_placeholder ) {
    // If there is no post thumbnail,
    // Return a default image
    if ( '' == $image_placeholder ) {
        return '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-thumbnail.png"/>';
    }
    // Else, return the post thumbnail
    return $image_placeholder;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'mlnc_filter_post_thumbnail_html' );
```

Another way is to go where the image is outputting and add an If statement like below:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} else { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-image.jpg"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: is this for elementor pro? if not then its not working

Comment: Ι usually don't use plugins at all, that's why I asked you in the first place if it's using the default wp image. Either way the second part you can use it everywhere you like

Comment: is there a way to do this?

Comment: What if i use CPT and the post type is not post but something else?